# Developing Component: Error With Menu Item

Tags: php, joomla, components

I'm trying to learn how to develop a Joomla component, according to this tutorial:
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!1.6_-_Part_01

I'm on Part 4. My problem is that I build the component and zip it, then install. But Joomla adds -"component" word after my component's name, in folders and in menu item.
For example, let's say my component's name is "stack". So it's "com_stack". I build it that way, when I install it, folders in `/components` and `/administrator/components` are `"com_stackcomponent"`. And the link under Components menu is `"administrator/index.php?option=com_stackcomponent"` So it doesn't open it.

I can manually change folders' names, but how to change the link under menu?

Or, how to solve it from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the link in the menu, go to phpMyAdmin and search for "stackcomponent", then edit accordingly.

Unfortunately its not really a solution to your problem - I've not used Joomla 1.6 so don't know why it would be doing that.

Comment: So you think it's something happening with SQL? I have install SQL query which is empty yet.

Comment: Well to fix the item in the menu you'd need to rename the value in the database, but its only a temporary solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

Its doing that because you stopped at step 4 of 17 steps.  A few steps later it explains how to properly name the component.